# Difference between RX-missed, RX-errors and RX-nombuf

Tags: dpdk

I got the NIC stats while using the testpmd (comes along with DPDK). But, i am not able to understand the meaning of the all the counter ( RX-missed, RX-errors and RX-nombuf).

Please let me know exactly in which scenario the above mentioned counters will be incremented ?

Below is sample stats of a NIC using testpmd

```
testpmd> show port stats all

######################## NIC statistics for port 0  ########################
RX-packets: 7467716    RX-missed: 9751220    RX-bytes:  11335992888
RX-errors: 0
RX-nombuf:  980047
TX-packets: 0          TX-errors: 0          TX-bytes:  0

Throughput (since last show)
Rx-pps:        40950
Tx-pps:            0
############################################################################

######################## NIC statistics for port 1  ########################
RX-packets: 0          RX-missed: 0          RX-bytes:  0
RX-errors: 0
RX-nombuf:  0
TX-packets: 7450911    TX-errors: 0          TX-bytes:  11310482898

Throughput (since last show)
Rx-pps:            0
Tx-pps:        40946
############################################################################
```

Answer (score 4):

> RX-missed

Total of RX packets dropped by the HW, because there are no available buffer (i.e. RX queues are full).

The main reason for full RX queues is a "slow" application, which is not able to process packets in a rate they arrive on interface.

> RX-errors

Total number of erroneous received packets, i.e. packets with incorrect checksum, runts, giants etc.

> RX-nombuf

Total number of RX mbuf allocation failures, i.e. RX packet was drop due to lack of free mbufs in the mempool.

Those counters are described here:
http://dpdk.org/doc/api/structrte__eth__stats.html